# Cannot change current tile

Tags: andengine

```
for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {

    shell.setCurrentTileIndex(i);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I just want to change each tile within a for loop but what happen is the only last value are change after 7 seconds. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `TimerHandler` object , something like that :

```
TimerHandler timer =  new TimerHandler(1, true,  new ITimerCallback() {


    @Override
    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

      shell.setCurrentTileIndex(i);
      if(i == 6)
        // unregister your timer

    }

    });

//register your timer
```

Comment: I am a new at andengine and i cannot understand this timer.hope you show me how could I unregister a timer and register it? please show me.thanks. :)

Comment: how can i increment the integer i?